# No index exists for this sort - couchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Getting error when accesing the data by using sort method

Error is

> No index exists for this sort

Create index code is

```js
db.createIndex({
    index: { fields: ["timestamp", "upVote"] },
}).then(() => {
    this.intitialDatafromDB(db);
});
```

find function is

```js
db.find({
   selector: { upVote: { $gt: 5 } },
   sort: [{ upVote: "desc" }],
   fields: ["news"],
}).then((result: any) => {
    this.data = result.docs;
}).catch((err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your query is failing is that the order of index fields **matters**.

From the pouchdb documentation [Indexing on more than one field](https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html#more-than-one-field)

> One thing to note is that the order of these fields matters when
> creating your index

By specifying the index as so

```js
fields: ['timestamp','upVote']
```

The index looks like this

| timestamp | upVote |
| --- | --- |
| 1590399369500 | 3 |
| 1590399369600 | 4 |
| 1590399369700 | 1 |
| 1590399369700 | 2 |
| 1590399369700 | 3 |
| 1590399369800 | 1 |

Note the timestamp `1590399369700`, and how the secondary field `upVote` sorts.

If your index fields were ordered like so

```js
fields: ['upVote','timestamp']
```

Given the theoretical data above, the index would look like this

| upVote | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1590399369700 |
| 1 | 1590399369800 |
| 2 | 1590399369700 |
| 3 | 1590399369500 |
| 3 | 1590399369700 |
| 4 | 1590399369600 |

and your query would return the results you expect, as is demonstrated in the snippet below. I recommend reading over [Map/reduce queries](https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html); grasping the concepts presented in that documentation will provide a deeper understanding of why this is so.

```js
const g_result = 'result';
const getEl = id => document.getElementById(id);
let db;

async function view() {
  const view = getEl(g_result);

  const result = await db.find({
    selector: {
      upVote: {
        $gt: 5
      },
    },
    sort: [{
      'upVote': 'desc'
    }],
    fields: ['news','upVote']
  }, );

  view.innerText = JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 3);
}

// canned test documents
function getDocsToInstall() {
  return [{
      timestamp: 1590399369508,
      upVote: 3,
      news: "new item 1"
    },
    {
      timestamp: 1590399248600,
      upVote: 4,
      news: "new item 2"
    },
    {
      timestamp: 1590399248600,
      upVote: 5,
      news: "new item 3"
    },
    {
      timestamp: 1590399248700,
      upVote: 6,
      news: "new item 4"
    },
    {
      timestamp: 1590399248900,
      upVote: 7,
      news: "new item 5"
    },
    {
      timestamp: 1590399249000,
      upVote: 8,
      news: "new item 6"
    },
  ]
}

// init example db instance
async function initDb() {
  db = new PouchDB('test', {
    adapter: 'memory'
  });

  await db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall());
  await db.createIndex({
    index: {
      fields: ['upVote', 'timestamp']
    }
  });
};

(async() => {
  await initDb();
  await view();
})();
```

```css
https: //stackoverflow.com/questions/69122670/no-index-exists-for-this-sort-couchdb#
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb-7.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.find.min.js"></script>
<pre id='view'></pre>
<div style='margin-top:2em'></div>
<pre id='result'>
</pre>
```