# PouchDb: No matching index found, create an index to optimize query time

Tags: node.js, pouchdb

Init PouchDb:

```
const PouchDB = require("pouchdb");
const allDbs = require("pouchdb-all-dbs")

PouchDB.plugin(require("pouchdb-find"))

let POUCH_DB_DEFAULTS = {
  prefix: "http://budibase:budibase@localhost:4005",
}
const Pouch = PouchDB.defaults(POUCH_DB_DEFAULTS)

allDbs(Pouch)

module.exports = Pouch
```

Have created index:

```
db.createIndex({
    index: {
      fields: ['_id', 'username', 'userAccount', 'builder.app', 'builder.apps', 'builder.global', 'admin.apps', 'admin.global', 'roles']
      name: 'user-index'
    }
})
```

Finding documents:

```
getUserByNameOrAccount = async (username, userAccount) => {
    const db = getGlobalDB()
    let user
    const findBody = {
      fields: ['_id', 'username', 'userAccount'],
    }
    if (username) {
      findBody.selector = { username }
    } else if (userAccount) {
      findBody.selector = { userAccount }
    }
    var indexes = await db.getIndexes();
    var explanation = await db.explain(findBody)
    user = await db.find(findBody);
  
    return user
}
```

The value of `findBody`:

```
{
  fields: [
    "_id",
    "username",
    "userAccount",
  ],
  selector: {
    userAccount: "123456",
  },
}
```

Can find indexs in db.

The value of `indexs`：

```
{
  total_rows: 2,
  indexes: [
    {
      ddoc: null,
      name: "_all_docs",
      type: "special",
      def: {
        fields: [
          {
            _id: "asc",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      ddoc: "_design/83c0f8306bf46f1487ce1482eefa9096a3208404",
      name: "user-index",
      type: "json",
      partitioned: false,
      def: {
        fields: [
          {
            _id: "asc",
          },
          {
            username: "asc",
          },
          {
            userAccount: "asc",
          },
          {
            "builder.app": "asc",
          },
          {
            "builder.apps": "asc",
          },
          {
            "builder.global": "asc",
          },
          {
            "admin.apps": "asc",
          },
          {
            "admin.global": "asc",
          },
          {
            roles: "asc",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

The value of `explanation`：

```
{
  dbname: "global-db",
  index: {
    ddoc: null,
    name: "_all_docs",
    type: "special",
    def: {
      fields: [
        {
          _id: "asc",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  partitioned: "undefined",
  selector: {
    userAccount: {
      $eq: "123456",
    },
  },
  opts: {
    use_index: [
    ],
    bookmark: "nil",
    limit: 25,
    skip: 0,
    sort: {
    },
    fields: [
      "_id",
      "username",
      "userAccount",
    ],
    partition: "",
    r: [
      49,
    ],
    conflicts: false,
    stale: false,
    update: true,
    stable: false,
    execution_stats: false,
  },
  limit: 25,
  skip: 0,
  fields: [
    "_id",
    "username",
    "userAccount",
  ],
  mrargs: {
    include_docs: true,
    view_type: "map",
    reduce: false,
    partition: null,
    start_key: null,
    end_key: "<MAX>",
    direction: "fwd",
    stable: false,
    update: true,
    conflicts: "undefined",
  },
}
```

The value of `user`:

```
{
  docs: [
    {
      _id: "us_1792b3ba423d4902b7fe4764246df474",
      username: "testname",
      userAccount: "123456",
    },
  ],
  bookmark: "g1AAAAB2eJzLYWBgYMpgSmHgKy5JLCrJTq2MT8lPzkzJBYorlxbHG5pbGiUZJyWaGBmnmFgaGCWZp6WamJuZGJmYpaSZmJuAtHLAtBKrKQsAaqcf8w",
  warning: "No matching index found, create an index to optimize query time.",
}
```

So why PouchDB's find() always says "no matching index"?

Comment: The order of the index fields matters.  Create an index with just the field `'userAccount'`, or at least have `userAccount` be the first index field. See https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html#more-than-one-field

Comment: Tanks, creating some indexes width single field work for me. However, I did't figure out how the order  of the index fields works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No index exists for this sort - couchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69122670/no-index-exists-for-this-sort-couchdb)

Comment: Yes, certainly.